# How to take values from a disabled field to insert?

Tags: php

I have a form that has input fields that are disabled but none the less it holds values.

How can i take into a variable and insert.  I tried:

```
   $value1 = $_POST['test'];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. Disabled fields are not posted to your server. Readonly fields are posted, so if you really need the contents of the field you could change it to be readonly instead of disabled.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't**.

The best you can do is, use some sort of `default value`:

```
function post( $fieldName, $default = '' )
{
   if( !isset( $_POST[ $fieldName ] ) )
   {
      return $default;
   }
   else
   {
      return $_POST[ $fieldName ];
   }
}

$value1 = post('test', '0');
```

Or as @Arjan said, change your form to `readonly`:

```
<input type='text' name='test' readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how the `disabled` attribute works. When a form control is disabled, the value will be ignored when the form is submitted and the key will not be present in `$_POST` (or `$_GET`).

If you want the value to be present in the submitted data, but you don't want the user to be able to change the value on the page (which I imagine is what you are trying to acheive) use `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled="disabled"`.

**EDIT**

The `<select>` element does not have a `readonly` attribute. The above information still stands as it *will* work for `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s.

The solution to your problem here would be to disable the select and use a hidden input to send the value back to the server - e.g.

When the select is enabled:

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country">
  <!-- options here -->
</select>
```

...and when it is disabled:

```
<select class="txtbx1" name="country_disabled" disabled="disabled">
  <!-- options here, with appropriate value having `selected="selected"` -->
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="value_of_field" />
```

But the main thing is that how to set these Hidden field when i change the Select field . and how to set at Submit form time . ?

Comment: please try to respond the question - the question is about inputs so, the select example is quite unnecessary.